# CSS3 animations in Internet Explorer 11 (Windows Phone 8.1 version)

Tags: css, internet-explorer, windows-phone, mobile-browser

I have problem with my new website and it's CSS3 effects. On PC everythink work (almost) well, but on my Windows Phone 8.1 device is behaviour of CSS3 animations little bit weird. I'm pretty sure tkat my code is fine - don't you if there are any limitations in WP version of Internet Explorer?

I want to post screenshots there but I can't. Hard to explain my problem better.

Comment: The documentation provided by Microsoft describes support for most CSS(3) features: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn736066%28v=vs.85%29.aspx (overview)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh771874(v=vs.85).aspx (animation)

Comment: Can you give us an code example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: I'm not trying - I done it... In desktop browsers everything works vell, but not in Internet Explorer Mobile. If you can, please visit http://www.honzachalupa.cz/ from smartphone and you will probably see the problem in the header section. Weird shadows during and after the title animation.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the animation property unprefixed. This shouldn't be a problem for Windows Phone IE.

```
header div#headerTitle_Layer1 {
    animation-name: loadAnimation_Layer1;
}
```

I've tested your site in IE on Windows Phone 8.1 on a Lumia 930 and 630 and I'm pretty sure the animation is working correctly (colors and slide-in).

If you want to support Safari, Safari iOS, Opera, Android and older versions of Chrome you'll have to prefix the properties.

```
header div#headerTitle_Layer1 {
    -webkit-animation-name: loadAnimation_Layer1;  
    animation-name: loadAnimation_Layer1;
}
```

See a full support chart [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation).

Comment: I added prefixes week ago and nothing changed for me. It really looks fine, for you? I see weird "ghosts" of the header title ( <HonzaChalupa/> ) on every load. When I scroll down and back up it disappear and everything is great (until next load or page redirection).